# SAS Send Email containing Graphic AND Table in Body

Tags: sas

It's possible to email a graphic. It's possible to send a table. But I can't seem to figure out how to do both in the same email.

For example, here is sending a plot:

```
FILENAME SENDMAIL EMAIL 
    TO=("test.test@test.ca") 
    FROM=("test.test@test.ca") 
    ATTACH=("&REPORT_DIR./EMAIL.png" INLINED="SGPLOT")
    TYPE="TEXT/HTML" 
    SUBJECT="Some Report";

ODS _ALL_ CLOSE; 
ODS LISTING GPATH="&REPORT_DIR";
ODS GRAPHICS / RESET=INDEX OUTPUTFMT=PNG IMAGENAME='EMAIL';
PROC SGPLOT DATA=WORK.DEV_VISUAL;
TITLE "INVENTORY VALUE RELATIVE TO TARGET";
SERIES X=DATE Y=INV_VALUE / LINEATTRS=(COLOR=BLUE);
SERIES X=DATE Y=TARGET_AMOUNT / LINEATTRS=(COLOR=BLACK); 
YAXIS LABEL="OH INVENTORY VALUE";
RUN;

DATA _NULL_;
FILE SENDMAIL;  
PUT "<HTML>";
PUT "<BODY>";
PUT "<BODY>";
PUT "<IMG SRC=cid:SGPLOT>";
PUT "</BODY>";
PUT "</HTML>";
RUN;
```

And here is sending a report:

```
FILENAME SENDMAIL EMAIL 
    TO=("test.test@test.ca") 
    FROM=("test.test@test.ca") 
    TYPE="TEXT/HTML" 
    SUBJECT="Some Report";

ODS HTML BODY=OUTBOX STYLE=MINIMAL FILE=SENDMAIL;

PROC REPORT NOWD 
DATA=WORK.DEV_FINANCIAL
STYLE(report) = [cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 frame=hsides rules = groups font=(Arial,8pt, bold) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black]
STYLE(Header) = [just=c height=15 VERTICALALIGN=c foreground=white background=CX00669A font=(Arial,8pt, bold) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black]
STYLE(column)=[font=(Arial,8pt) foreground=black background=CXFFFFFF VJUST=C bordertopwidth=0 borderrightwidth=0 borderleftwidth=0 bordercolor=black tagattr='wraptext:no' width=1000%];
COLUMNS
DEVICE_PLANNER
INV_VALUE
TARGET_AMOUNT
DIFF_AMT
DIFF_PCT
PREV_INV_VAL
PCT_CHANGE;

DEFINE DEVICE_PLANNER/ DISPLAY 'Planner' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=130 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] GROUP;
DEFINE INV_VALUE/ DISPLAY 'Inventory Value' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=150 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] FORMAT=DOLLAR15.0 SUM;
DEFINE TARGET_AMOUNT/ DISPLAY 'Target Amount' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=150 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] FORMAT=DOLLAR15.0 SUM;
DEFINE DIFF_AMT/ DISPLAY 'Difference ($)' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=150 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] FORMAT=DOLLAR15.0 SUM;
DEFINE DIFF_PCT/ DISPLAY 'Difference (%)' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=150 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] FORMAT=PERCENT15.0 COMPUTED;
DEFINE PREV_INV_VAL/ DISPLAY 'Previous Inventory Value' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=150 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] FORMAT=DOLLAR15.0 SUM;
DEFINE PCT_CHANGE/ DISPLAY 'Day over Day Change (%)' STYLE(COLUMN)=[WIDTH=150 FONT=(Arial,10pt) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black] FORMAT=PERCENT15.0 COMPUTED;
RBREAK AFTER/SUMMARIZE STYLE=[foreground=BLACK BACKGROUND=#DEDDED FONT=(Arial,10pt, BOLD) borderbottomwidth=1 bordertopwidth=1 borderrightwidth=1 borderleftwidth=1 bordercolor=black];
COMPUTE DIFF_PCT;
DIFF_PCT = (INV_VALUE.SUM / TARGET_AMOUNT.SUM) - 1;
ENDCOMP;
COMPUTE PCT_CHANGE;
PCT_CHANGE = (INV_VALUE.SUM - PREV_INV_VAL.SUM) / PREV_INV_VAL.SUM;
ENDCOMP;
COMPUTE AFTER;
DEVICE_PLANNER = "TOTAL";
ENDCOMP;
RUN;

ODS HTML CLOSE;
```

I guess the issue is that: when sending a graphic, the code is HTML based. But when sending the report, the code is using this ODS functionality. I am not sure how to reconcile the two of them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Found a comprehensive post from Chris Hemedinger.  See the end about using HTML5 for embedding images, but check that it is supported by your email client. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-send-email-using-SAS/ta-p/746523 .  I've always been wary of trusting an email client to interpret HTML well.  Sometimes it's safer to attach a PDF.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2017/04/21/use-sas-send-email-embeds-graph-body-email/ simpler example, replace proc print with the proc report and that should be good to go. Note this is the second example on the page.